# Как лучше разместить блоки?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сверстать первый макет,вот только не знаю как сверстать данные блоки,чтобы это было максимально правильно.
 собирался взять в общий див.
потом на 1 строчке 2 дива. Допустим 1 блоку ширину 33% второму 66%
на 2 строчке 3 дива,навесить одинаковый класс
на 3 строчке аналогично 1
и 4 строчка аналогично 2.
зафлоатить это дело влево.
Но мне кажется что это слишком кривой вариант,и есть куда удачнее

Answer (score 1):

**Например с float:**

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}

.col-13 {float:left; height: 100%; width: 33.3333%; background: lightblue;}
.col-23 {float:left; height: 100%; width: 66.66666%;}

.img-1 {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large/loose-goose-iv-hot-air-balloon-rally-img-6492-torrey-smith.jpg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.img-2 {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large/loose-goose-iv-hot-air-balloon-rally-img-6492-torrey-smith.jpg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.row  p {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-13"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
<div class="col-23">
  <div class="img-1"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-13"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p></div>
<div class="col-13"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p></div>
<div class="col-13"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-23">
  <div class="img-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-13"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p></div>
</div>
```

**С flex:**

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    justify-content: space-between;
  
}

.col-13 {height: 100%; width: 33.3333%; background: lightblue;}
.col-23 {height: 100%; width: 66.66666%;}

.img-1 {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large/loose-goose-iv-hot-air-balloon-rally-img-6492-torrey-smith.jpg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.img-2 {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large/loose-goose-iv-hot-air-balloon-rally-img-6492-torrey-smith.jpg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.row  p {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-13"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
<div class="col-23">
  <div class="img-1"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-13"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p></div>
<div class="col-13"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p></div>
<div class="col-13"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-23">
  <div class="img-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-13"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p></div>
</div>
```

**С table:**

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  
}

.col-13 {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; height: 100%; width: 33.3333%; background: lightblue;}
.col-23 {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; height: 100%; width: 66.66666%;}

.img-1 {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large/loose-goose-iv-hot-air-balloon-rally-img-6492-torrey-smith.jpg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.img-2 {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large/loose-goose-iv-hot-air-balloon-rally-img-6492-torrey-smith.jpg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.row  p {  
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 200px;  
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-13"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
<div class="col-23">
  <div class="img-1"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-13"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p></div>
<div class="col-13"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p></div>
<div class="col-13"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-23">
  <div class="img-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-13"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите писать вручную или допустимо использование фреймворков? Если допустимо - Bootstrap grid system в помощь. В данной сеточной системе страница по умолчанию поделена на 12 колонок. То есть Ваши блоки 1/3 и 2/3 можно прописать так:

```html
<!--РЯД-->
<div class="row">
  <!--КОЛОНКА ЗАНИМАЮЩАЯ 1/3 СТРАНИЦЫ-->
  <div class="col-lg-4">
     ...
  </div>
   <!--КОЛОНКА ЗАНИМАЮЩАЯ 2/3 СТРАНИЦЫ-->
  <div class="col-lg-8">
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

По аналогии строим блоки, занимающие 1/3 часть страницы:

```html
<!--РЯД-->
<div class="row">
  <!--КОЛОНКА ЗАНИМАЮЩАЯ 1/3 СТРАНИЦЫ-->
  <div class="col-lg-4">
     ...
  </div>
   <!--КОЛОНКА ЗАНИМАЮЩАЯ 1/3 СТРАНИЦЫ-->
  <div class="col-lg-4">
     ...
  </div>
  <!--КОЛОНКА ЗАНИМАЮЩАЯ 1/3 СТРАНИЦЫ-->
  <div class="col-lg-4">
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Лично мое мнение - использовать фреймворк - хорошо. Сразу решаются вопросы базовой адаптивности и есть набор полезных классов для верстки.